# Product of inner products

Tags: inner-products, products

Is product of innerproduct again a inner product of two vectors? 
For example - Is $ (< u,v >)(< x,y >) = < m,n > $? And if yes is m and n unique and how do we calculate those?

Comment: Well, any scalar is an inner product of two vectors. Take arbitrary two nonorthogonal vectors, then their inner product is nonzero, so you can scale one of them (or both) to get the wished scalar.

Answer (score 17):

Hint:
$$\langle x, y\rangle \langle w, z\rangle =  \langle \langle x, y\rangle w, z\rangle $$

Answer (score 3):

Of course the product, which is after all a scalar (call it $S$) , can be written as an inner product of two vectors, e.g., $\vec{n} = (S, 0, 0, \ldots), \vec{m} = (1, 0, 0, \ldots)$.  But the decomposition of that scalar is not unique, and in fact, you can find an infinite number of correct $\vec{m} $ cevtors for any specified non-zero $\vec{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to find such vector, in your example the answer could by (for example):

$$m=<u,v>x, n=y$$

or

$$m=<x,y>u, n=v$$

So it isn't unique.