# Why is $\langle x, y\rangle \langle w, z\rangle = \langle \langle x, y\rangle w, z\rangle$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

This answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995668/1103382
writes that $$\langle x, y\rangle \langle w, z\rangle =  \langle \langle x, y\rangle w, z\rangle$$
is true. Why is this the case? It feels like it would be a basic propert, but the only properties about inner product that I know are about additivity and homogeneity.

Comment: If you view $\langle x, y \rangle$ as a whole, it is just some element in the field $\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. So by homogeneity you can move it inside the second inner product.

Comment: $\langle x,y \rangle$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help if you write $\lambda=\langle x,y\rangle$? Then
$$
\langle x,y\rangle\,\langle w,z\rangle=\lambda\,\langle w,z\rangle
=\langle \lambda w,z\rangle=\langle\langle x,y\rangle\,w,z\rangle. 
$$